# Is it detect iPhone app price change?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store

One of my project need a function to detect the price change of the app in app store.
Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want your app to be able to find out (and display) what its own price is (since that could change after the app is released)?

Comment: yes, I hope to detect the price change and reminder the user

Comment: you want to remind the user of the price of the app that they are already using, and thus have already bought? Or of the price of OTHER apps?

Comment: Why? For them to be using your app, they must have already downloaded it, which means they already paid for it. Any updates are free, and no amount of price changing will change that, so it's pointless to inform existing users of price changes on the App Store. If the app was free in the first place and you change it to being a paid app, that still won't matter because existing users won't have to pay the price change even if they download the app again.

Comment: no, I hope to reminder users the price change,

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/app/appbzr-find-great-apps-price/id347830285?mt=8

Comment: They will have already bought the app! You cannot charge them more once they've purchased it!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the iTunes JSON API with the App ID to find the price. Here's an example for iMovie for iPhone:

http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsLookup?id=377298193

You'll see that in `data["results"][0]["price"]` the price is $4.99.